# Action Bar in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-2.2-froyo

I have installed FaceBook apk on my Android 2.2 version.When I click on the FB icon, I can see it has got many beautiful features, popups,slidings, graphics to view. Now, I got a task to create certain screens similar to that of FB application on Android 2.2.On one of the screen, in the "ACTION BAR", I want an icon at the left (i should click on the icon to go to next screen),the title as "Grocery" in the center, and then the Exit icon(to close the screen).Coding is much appreciated.Please help me in solving this as am newbie to Android world!!!

Comment: [Here](http://appfulcrum.com/2010/08/29/simple-actionbar-for-android-application/) Some simple example of Action-bar [Another](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/ActionBarTabs.html) Example.may this help you

Answer (score 2):

Consider using ActionBarSherlock to create an ActionBar that is similar to what Facebook has, but is compatible with the newer Android 4.0 user interface guidelines.

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

That being said, consider looking at the [Android Design](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html) pages.  The Facebook application is not the best example for following these guidelines.  In general, icons on the left of an ActionBar should navigate up to a previous state or head to home.  The title of the application should be left-justified next to the left button, and the right side should contain actions (buttons, etc) as well as any overflow menu.

Comment: Thank you!!! I shall check the link provided for ActionBarSherlock!!!